# Is there a utility for the Mac (OS X Lion) to monitor cpu and disk usage per process over a period of time?

Tags: macos, monitoring, cpu-usage, disk-io

I am looking for a good utility running on OS X Lion that would give me a per process summary of CPU usage and Disk I/Os. I don't want to monitor the instant usage, but to find out the average CPU and disk usage over a period of time (like a day of work) for each process.

I also have a VM on my Mac running WinXP on VMWare Fusion, so if you know of a similar utility for PC, it would be useful to.